# Mac Terminal Renaming Bulk files Randomly

Tags: macos, batch, rename, batch-rename

I have googled and looked on here but nothing is as basic as I want it.

Whats the best way to rename a folder of both `.jpg` and `.JPG` files to a random number - I have 250 images and I randomly want them renamed to a `num.jpg?`